# How to access the data from json multidimensional array

Tags: jquery, json

I have a result json like this

```
[
       {"courseStarted" :[
               {"CategoryName":"CategoryName","courseName" :"Equipment Course", "seriesName": "Free Education", "courseDetails" :[
                       {"totalLessons" :"2", "NoLessonComplete":"1", "lastviewed":"date", "lessonDetails":[
                               {"lessonId":"342367","quiz":"quizReady"},
                               {"lessonId" :"345345", "quiz":"quizReady"},
                               {"lessonId":"435435","quiz":"quizReady"},
                               {"lessonId":"4234234", "quiz":"quizFailed"},
                               {"lessonId":"4234234","quiz":"quizPassed"}
                       ]}
               ]}
       ]},
       {"courseStarted" :[
               {"CategoryName":"CategoryName","courseName" :"Equipment Course1", "seriesName": "Free Education1", "courseDetails" :[
                       {"totalLessons" :"21", "NoLessonComplete":"11", "lastviewed":"date1", "lessonDetails":[
                               {"lessonId":"3423671","quiz":"quizReady"},
                               {"lessonId" :"3453451", "quiz":"quizReady"},
                               {"lessonId":"4354351","quiz":"quizReady"},
                               {"lessonId":"42342341", "quiz":"quizReady"},
                               {"lessonId":"42342341","quiz":"quizPassed"}
                       ]}
               ]}
       ]}

    ]
```

from this json output how can i access the value of lessonId using the $.each function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569372/jquery-each-json-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.each(data, function(){

    // Print course name
    console.log(this.courseStarted[0].courseName);

    $.each(this.courseStarted[0].courseDetails[0].lessonDetails, function(){
        // Print lesson id
        console.log(this.lessonId);
    });

});
```

Comment: Yah it is working. But how could it getting the value by calling 0th element of course started. It should be incremented like for first this.courseStarted[0].courseName and for second this.courseStarted[1].courseName like that. I got it working but i did'nt get the workflow, i mean i did'nt getting how it's working. Can you tell me the theory behind this.

Comment: @user359187 If you look at `courseStarted` in your object it is always an array with exactly one value. That value is an object which has a courseName. In the code you posted you have two course names. `data[0].courseStarted[0].courseName` and `data[1].courseStarted[0].courseName`. The `$.each` handles the iteration through the data array. Does that make sense now?